# How to get a image from Google drive link using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

Hello all am trying to get the image from Google drive link and upload the same to Amazon S3 location using laravel php.

Can any on please help me with the best possible way to do so.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Laravel Http Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client) to download the image to a local temporary folder.

Then use the [Laravel Filesystem S3](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem) driver to upload the image again.

Reading above documentation you should be good to go pretty quick!

Comment: Will it get a file download from Google drive link

Comment: can you show me example link? and how big are the files?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wm29Pajll5k2PMwL2GZucn8sXmXm5qQy/view?usp=sharing ex this is a link and it wont be too heavy a image

Comment: the link you sent me seems to need additional authentication. it's probably easier if you use publicly available links. you can then follow the scheme above. otherwise you will need to read through the google auth guidelines ..